# Document library Custom Column Problem

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom-field-types

I have a document library, where I created a custom field, Now I am not sure how to add value to it. If I add a new folder or new document, I am not getting any field to enter the custom column value, which I created!!

Comment: when creating your new column, did you choose to add this new column to all library content types?

Comment: How did u create that field... create column??? or using list definition???

Comment: @Paddy I used custom Fields from list's ribbon.

Comment: I think... somehow... u got it readonly (fields)... Try the 3rd party tool like SharePoint Manager to make them editable(readonly=false)...

Comment: Thanks paddy, yes that is true, when I go to data sheet view, it shows read only for that field !!! Can I force the field to have data while adding it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... 1st make it editable... and set default value for the column... so that you can have data in it while adding... :)

Comment: It is working now :)